# How to use SCons lex builder with variant directories

Tags: lex, flex-lexer, scons

I'm trying to build a complex application with flex lexer using SCons. To build debug/release variants I'm using VariantDir().

The problem is that I can't force lex builder to generate lexer header in variant build directory. It isn't a big problem itself but it forces SCons to think that lexer is always out of date.

`SConstruct` contents:

```
VariantDir('build', '.', duplicate=0)
SConscript('build/SConscript')
```

`SConscript` contents:

```
env = Environment(LEXFLAGS='--header-file=scanner.h')
env.Program(target='scanner', source='scanner.l')
```

Full source to represent this problem is here: https://gist.github.com/g7r/4257f273715cadcf0d36

First `scons.py --debug=explain` run gives us this:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build
scons: building `build/scanner.c' because it doesn't exist
flex --header-file=scanner.h -t scanner.l > build/scanner.c
scons: building `build/scanner.o' because it doesn't exist
gcc -o build/scanner.o -c build/scanner.c
scons: building `build/scanner' because it doesn't exist
gcc -o build/scanner build/scanner.o
scons: done building targets.
```

Second run gives this:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build
scons: building `build/scanner.h' because it doesn't exist
flex --header-file=scanner.h -t scanner.l > build/scanner.c
scons: done building targets.
```

So second run rebuilds the lexer because `scanner.h` was generated in root directory instead of `build` directory.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to do it right?

Comment: Where is the scanner.h file after the first run and before the second run? If you run it a third time, do you get the same result as the second time? I would imagine so. I think the solution might be to do this: env = Environment(LEXFLAGS='--header-file=build/scanner.h')

Comment: If what I just commented fixes the problem, I can show you how to do this by adding the variant_dir to the call to SConscript() and removing the call to VariantDir() which will make the build scripts and paths more intuitive.

Comment: @Brady, your solution doesn't help. If I specify `--header-file=build/scanner.h` SCons keeps rebuilding lexer due to missing `build/build/scanner.h`.

Comment: Hmmm strange. Where is the scanner.h file after the first run?

Comment: With `--header-file=scanner.h` `scanner.h` appears in the project root directory.

Comment: With `--header-file=build/scanner.h` `scanner.h` appears in `build` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Consider combining the call to VariantDir() with the call to SConscript() which usually makes the paths in the build scripts more intuitive. Also, I suspect (unfortunately) the call to VariantDir() is confusing the SCons flex builder.

Here is an example:

```
SConscript('SConscript', variant_dir='build', duplicate=0)
```

Chapters 14 and 15 of the [SCons user's guide](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idm18609400) give a good explanation of the SConscript() function.

Comment: Your recipe doesn't work. It gives `Ignoring missing SConscript 'build/SConscript'` error. If I change this to `SConscript('SConscript', variant_dir='build', duplicate=0)` SCons behaviour is the same as I've described in my question.

Comment: @SergejZagursky where is the SConscript build script? in the same directory as the SConstruct? If not, can you show the relevant project directory structure.

Comment: All source files and build scripts are in the same directory.

Comment: @SergejZagursky I updated the answer accordingly. Also, I originally left out the variant_dir='build'. This should work better now.

Comment: To be honest I also suspect that lex tool incorrectly handles builds with `VariantDir()`.

Comment: @SergejZagursky did it work any better with the latest udpate?

Comment: Nothing changes if I replace my original version of `SConstruct` with your `SConscript('SConscript', variant_dir='build', duplicate=0)`. As far as I can understand the manual it should behave exactly like mine `VariantDir('build', '.', duplicate=0); SConscript('build/SConscript')`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this old problem via a search - the problem isn't variant dirs per se, it's the use of the `--header-file` option and being in a subdirectory: SCons passes `LEXFLAGS` on as is when flex is called, but also extracts the header file name you asked for and adds it as a target - at which point it's subject to the SCons path interpretation rules, as in "relative to the directory of the SConscript", so flex generates the file one place via the issued command and SCons thinks it's a different place, thus the "always out of date".  There's more on this topic at https://github.com/SCons/scons/issues/4154.